# Changing title of UIButton using animationWithDuration has no delay or animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton

I have a start button with initial text "Start" hooked up to an action in Interface Builder.

However, the animation starts and finishes instantly, instead of taking 3 + 5 seconds. What is wrong with this code?

```
@interface ViewController()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)startPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:5
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
        animations:^{
            [self.startButton setTitle:@"New Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } 
        completion:nil];
}

@end
```

**Update**: Of course, these responses are correct. I used Jack Wu's suggestion, though without hiding the text, setTitle makes the button flash back on the screen.

```
- (IBAction)startPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:5
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{ self.startButton.alpha = 0; }
                     completion:^(BOOL c){ if (c) {
        self.startButton.hidden = YES;
        [self.startButton setTitle:@"newTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             self.startButton.hidden = NO;
                             self.startButton.alpha = 1;
                         }
                         completion:nil];

    }}];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that a button's title is animatable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting here...

Comment: If you want some sort of transition, maybe you can fade out the button in 1.5 seconds, change the text, then fade it back in with another 1.5 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A button's title is not an animatable property, so you're going to see it return immediately. That's by design. You can find the animatable properties of a UIView in its' [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html). Here's what they are as of today.

```
@property frame
@property bounds
@property center
@property transform
@property alpha
@property backgroundColor
@property contentStretch
```

Alternately, you can add two subview labels to your button and cross fade them in your animation.

Answer (score 1):

Title is not an animatable property of UIButton. As others have suggested, you would need to create an animation yourself by doing something like fading out the button, changing the title, and fading it back.

You could also write custom animation code that would take a bitmap snapshot of the button, lay that on top of the current button, change the button title under the bitmap snapshot, then fade out and remove the bitmap. That would give you a cross-fade effect, but it would be a fair amount of work.